# Does the glmulti function (from the gmulti package) need a set.seed value?

Tags: r, glm, glmulti

I am using glmulti to select a set of candidate generalized linear models and my variable importance values and 'best' model keep changing each time I run the model.

I am struggling to understand why this is, does glmulti need a set.seed value to make results reproducible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `glmulti` function is in the `glmulti` package.  (You should state this in your question...)  If so, the help page says that sometimes it uses a genetic algorithm to find the best model.  Those are indeed random algorithms, so you can expect to get an answer that depends on the random number seed.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am referring to the glmulti package (question edited). I am also using the genetic algorithm, but I cannot see anywhere where seeds are set of specified. Right now, each run produces a different result, unfortunately.

Comment: The normal way to set the seed is the `set.seed()` function, called once just before you generate a set of random values.  If you do something like `set.seed(123)` before calling `glmulti()`, do you get reproducible results?

Comment: I have tried that and still received different outputs. I am wondering if the seed is set somewhere else in the gmulti function.

Comment: `glmulti` depends on `rJava`, so it may be that it's using the Java random number generator.  I've got no idea if it's possible to set the seed for that; you'll have to ask the package maintainer.